# Size reported in Firefox and Firebug is different to Chrome and IE11

Tags: css, firefox

I am finding an inconsistency with the pixels that are being reported in the Box Model in Firefox 26 compared to what is being reported in Chrome v32 and IE 11.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="main">
    <div>Box Model Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main { border: 1px solid black; }
.main div { background-color: green; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid red;  height: 100px; width: 250px; }
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cz2fa/)

In Firefox v26 the box model reports a border of 1px instead of 2px for .main div. Furthermore the computed properties on Firefox show border as 1.6px. Looking at the code I would expect that the border is exactly 2px as shown in Chrome and IE. Why does is this different in Firefox?

Comment: Do you have the page zoomed in Firefox?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky You've pointed me in the right direction. I had reset the page zoom in Firefox but still the same. However I found that the Windows scaling level was at 125% instead of 100% on my computer. So it seems that Firefox takes the Windows setting into account and scales the web page accordingly. On the other hand Chrome doesn't seem to behave in this way.